# Error term average to zero?

Tags: regression, prediction

I am quite new to statistic and regression. In one of literature, the setting for prediction to estimate f in regression, the error term averages to zero.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any detailed context, I can only guess that the author means that the error term is assumed to be a random variable, of which mean is 0.